# Is there a way to switch tabview to the element being validated using required attribute HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, yui

I am using YUI tabview in my form, which has a submit button at the end (the 5th tab), the issue is that the validation is working fine, but I can not see the pop up message since I am in the last tabview(which contain the final submit button) instead of the tabview of the form element being checked ( with `checkValidity`).

I am using this :
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/tabview/frommarkup.html

This is the how it looks like : 
http://jsfiddle.net/D4GmQ/3/

When I click on the first submit button in the first tab it shows up the pop up , but when I click from the last one it throws a Javascript error.

my question is : is there a way to change the tab to the one containing the element being checked ?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't do anything...  Can you modify it to reproduce your problem?  There are no forms on your fiddle, nor do you attach event handlers to the buttons, so you won't get anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution for this problem, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4GmQ/7/)

You can compare it to the original issue [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D4GmQ/3/).

Since there is no YUI2 function that changes the tabView automatically, then the idea is to add a function that searches the input that will be validated and activates the tabView that contains it, this way we can see the html5 popup message.

```
    <div id="tab3"><p>Tab Three Content</p>
        <button onclick="ToolData.tabs.selectTab(0);"> submit </button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error:

```
An invalid form control with name='field1' is not focusable.
```

I don't think this is an easy one to solve, given your design.  I would suggest taking control of the form submission and doing your own validation.  You could validate each tab in turn and if you have an error, focus to the tab containing the field.  Sorry, HTH

Comment: Thanks Steve I already know about the error message, I am trying to find a way to catch the instant before the element is being checked, this way I can switch the YUI tab (since YUI is hiding the elements in the other tabs)